# How to read a specific line from file using line number without traversing whole file in java?

Tags: java, file, line

I want to access the file using specific line number without reading whole file.Is it possible in java?

Comment: You can use a LineNumberReader (a child of BufferedReader to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in any language unless the file has some sort of indexing feature.

Unless you know where the lines are you need to scan the file and count them. If you need to access the same file a lot you could always scan it once and build an index - you still need to do the first pass through though.